# CSS : How to set the top property relative to the bottom of the parent

Tags: css, position, postcss

I'm creating a class for a dropdown button, and I want the dropdown part to be a few pixels under the main button. 
The button is set to `relative`, and the ul to `absolute`. So far, so good. By default the ul's top is directly under the button's bottom. I want it to be 5px under it. But if I set the top property, it will take the top of the parent as origin. Is there anyway to make the origin the bottom of the parent ? 
I can't just take the parent's height + 5 or something like 110%, cause the parent's height might sometimes change from one button to another.

I'm using postcss by the way, it might offer more solutions.

```
.bouton-deroulant{
  @extend .bouton;
  position: relative;

  ul{
    display:none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 #c8b4a8;
  }

  &:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top : + 5px; // here is my problem
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: hello. have you tried : `top: calc(100% + 5px) ; `  .What is your HTML alike ? (:hover)

Comment: You can add `margin-top: 5px`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of margin top ! Thx for both great answers.